# PHP MySQL output category and subcategory if it exists

Tags: php, html, mysql, output

I have thinked at the following table structure:

```
id \ parent_id \ name

1  \ null      \ Tech
2  \ 1         \ Cameras
3  \ 1         \ Computers
4  \ 1         \ Gagets
5  \ 1         \ Printers
6  \ 5         \ Ink Printers
7  \ 5         \ Laser Printers
```

but i diddn't have a script with this functionality:

The output that i am hoping to get is either somenthing like this

```
<ul class="cate-item column">
<li class="cate-parent"><a href="#">Tech</a>
<ul class="cate-child">
<li><a href="#">Cameras</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

when none of the childs have a sub category, or something like this:

```
<ul class="cate-item column">

<li class="cate-parent"><a href="#">Tech</a>

<ul class="cate-child">
<li><a href="#">Cameras</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>

<ul class="sub-cate-child">
<li><a href="#">Laser Printers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ink Printers</a></li>
</ul>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```